# Сверх или сверх- ? Частица или предлог?

Tags: морфология, слитно-раздельно-дефис

Такое предложение: "Её любовь к детям была сверхвозможной". Подскажите, "сверх возможной" или "сверхвозможной"? На мой взгляд должно быть слитное составное слово, но не знаю наверняка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я тоже считаю, что должно быть слитное написание, сверх - это приставка.

Answer (score 1):

***СВЕРХ*ВОЗМОЖНЫЙ** пишется слитно, где сверх- это приставка, первая часть сложного слова.

**Сверх** может выступать и предлогом: сверх норм_ - сочетание предлога *сверх* и существительного *норма* в родительном падеже мн. числа.